# Block user from accessing "sudo su -"

Tags: sudo

How can I block a user not to use "sudo su -" command ? Because that will give him root access anyway. I want to limit him to read only permission for all files apart from what ever I give write access.

Comment: Standard users won't have permission unless you add permission in sudoers file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a user to have `sudo`  permission for other commands, but not to be able to log in as root, you need to edit the `visudo` file and specify the access you want the user to have.

```
sudo visudo
```

Then inside that file you would define the user and give permissions based on what you want that user to be able to do, for example

```
test    ALL=(ALL:`/home/test/) /home/test/, /usr/bin/vi, !/usr/bin/su
```

The above states that user test is allowed to access their home directory, run `vim` with `sudo` (as root) but nothing else. I am also explicitly telling the sudoers file to not allow the user to run `su`.

You should take a moment and read the [sudoers manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/sudoers.5.html), it explains everything.

Comment: "for all you haters out there, I do not have the reputation to comment yet" Haters? We have rules for a reason, you only need 50 rep to comment, earn it. Do you really think insulting the community will get you votes?

Comment: !/usr/bin/su entry in visudo answered my query. yes, I wanted to block the user from accessing root. Thanks for your help.  Will go through Sudoers manual to check further.

Comment: Can you mark it as correct?

Comment: Using '!' on a command spec is a VERY risky thing, since it's so easy to work around.  I'd recommend a classic 'mostly closed' setup, and never allowing anything in the list of tools that would also allow privilege escalation.

(vi is in that list.  Consider something newer)